# Can not disable the default blocks available under block layout

Tags: blocks

I installed Drupal 8.3 and I am facing the following issue: There is no disable region available under block layout, but the same is available under Drupal 8.2.6.

Is this an issue with Drupal core or with the theme I am using?

Comment: i think the issue is with the theme you are using. Change the theme to one if the default drupal theme to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an issue, please read [release notes](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/plain/core/CHANGELOG.txt) and under heading "Improved site building and administration:"

Removed the 'disabled' region from block administration.

Now there is an option to "**Disable**" block.

[image]